# how to understand this python code ,thanks a lot

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([[1,2,3]])
print(p[np.array([0]), np.array([1,0,0])])

# output:[2,1,1]
```

I am trying to understand why this output is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is (1,3) shape array.  The indexing, which can also be written as

```
p[ 0, [1,0,0]]
```

selects `p[0,1]`, `p[0,0]` and `p[0,0]`, that is the 2 and 1 (twice).

It's straight forward indexing with a list or array, also called advanced indexing.